# Ignore generation of declarations for specific files

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
src/
    user.ts
    department.ts
```

using above as a context structure, if i do `tsc` is it possible to ignore/prevent generaton of declaration files for `department.ts` within tsconfig or webpack while bulding the app?
Currently its generating declaration for all the files within src directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `exclude` key in the `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
   // ...other config options
   "exclude": ["src/user.ts", "src/department.ts"]
}
```

See [the TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude) for more details

Comment: correct, I did miss the part that says if the file is being imported somewhere it will be included in the build, so for exclude to work the file has to be "independent" meaning included files does not import that file to be excluded